# How do I disable the SSL requirement in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, ssl, mysql-workbench

It seems that an SSL connection is required to use MySQL Workbench, and I don't think this is the case with previous versions.

I remember SSL connections used to be optional. After I updated it, all options are locked to require SSL.

How do I bypass this? I'm just a student and setting up SSL is out of my reach.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: How can this be set for new connection automatically?

Comment: This seems to be a problem in Workbench on Windows v8.0.27. Please clarify if you see this on other versions/systems too.

Comment: The new version 8.0.28 fixes this and the "If Available" option on SSL is back. Just updating should fix the issue now.

Comment: This is a duplicated question that belongs already to dba and I saw it at serverfault

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I solved this by editing the *connections.xml* configuration file.

Under *~/.mysql/workbench/connections.xml*, I searched for the connection name and changed

```xml
<value type="int" key="useSSL">2</value>
```

to

```xml
<value type="int" key="useSSL">1</value>
```

Comment: FYI: For Windows, the path is C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\connections.xml

Comment: or Win+R and copy paste `%AppData%\MySQL\Workbench\connections.xml`

Comment: Can confirm this works on Windows. But I had to set connections.xml to read-only via file-properties to get this to work. Workbench was rewriting the useSSL property every time I restarted workbench.

Comment: This didn't work for me on `wsl2` on `Win11` with `Ubuntu20.04`, but @lixiaoshi's comment worked (downgrade to `8.0.26`.

Comment: Does not work on win10 and 8.0.27. I still get the SSL Error. This solution  worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70156541/1988569

Answer (score 74):

Here is the correct solution for version +8.0.x.
When the program starts, the edited configuration files are changed again.

Therefore, you need to add `useSSL=1` in advanced.

[image: ssl req]

Comment: Thanks for the easy and simple solution

Comment: Seems like this should be the answer

Comment: This answer works for the current session only. The next time you open the MySQL Workbench you will have to type it again. The answer given by @Fez is the best because adds the "No" option to your "Use SSL" dropdown list and once chosen it remains selected.

Comment: In the same place, use useSSL=0 to remove the SSL restriction.

Answer (score 17):

#### MySQL Workbench has released 8.0.28

It solves this bug. Wow. I am happy.

In Mac OS X there is this issue.

My version is *mysql-workbench-community-8.0.27-macos-x86_64.dmg*.

I have downgraded to *mysql-workbench-community-8.0.26-macos-x86_64.dmg*, and it has solved it.

This issue has been reported to the MySQL team. See *[Test Connection in Workbench fails since SSL required](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=105327)* (Bug #105327).

In the bug report, the development team replies that this issue will be fixed in 8.0.28.

Someone may be waiting for the fix, but check for the newest version on [the download page](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/).

Comment: Same here, the option `No` appeared after I downgraded to `8.0.26`.

Comment: Can confirm! It's available, upgraded to "8.0.28" on Ubuntu 20.04 and the "If Available" option on SSL is back. Just updating should fix the issue now.

Answer (score 16):

I found this solution on Stack Exchange and worked for me just fine on Windows 10. This is the original post: *[MySQL Workbench: "ssl is required but the server doesn't support it"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/199154/mysql-workbench-ssl-is-required-but-the-server-doesnt-support-it)*.

Look for the [fehrlich's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/199154/mysql-workbench-ssl-is-required-but-the-server-doesnt-support-it/303101#303101). I will describe it here as in the original post:

You can bring back the old SSL options in 8.0.27:

- Close MySQL Workbench
- Go to you MySQL Workbench install folder (p.e. C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE)
- open the file modules/data/mysql_rdbms_info.xml
- replace all occurrences of
- ">2|Require,3|Require and Verify CA,4|Require and Verify Identity"
- with ">0|No,1|If available,2|Require,3|Require and Verify CA,4|Require
  and Verify Identity"

Now you have the old options back.

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rB9P.png)

Comment: This is the best answer so far, because it adds the "No" option to the "Use SSL" dropdown list and the value remains selected.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it may be the right approach for you, but I downgraded my version of MySQL Workbench to 6.3 and uninstalled the previous version. It will then give you the "if available" option for SSL. As you are right, it is not the case for previous versions, however you do lose a few more modern features in the process.

*[MySQL Product Archives](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/)*

Another solution as well is to connect to connect to the database in 6.3 and since the configuration saves are in the same location, upgrade to 8.0 where it will still have the old configuration file and won't use SSL due to backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thanks, I had to do this too. I don't know what's going on in Workbench's developers head but it's definitely a mess.

Comment: 8.0.26 still has the "no" and "if available" option, so no need to go as far as 6.3.

Answer (score 1):

I am using MySQL server 5.6. Uninstall and install MySQL Workbench 8. It's working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error when I was trying to export or import database from AWS RDS. I had Mysql Workbench on my system and also had Mysql installed locally.

As none of the solution mentioned here worked for me, I went further to investigate the error. I found out that the Workbench `Default Target Mysql` is 8.0.15 and my natively installed version of Mysql was 5.7.24, meaning the Mysqldump tool I was using didn't support the SSL protocol.

I bumped the natively installed Mysql to 8.0.18, and pointed the dump tool to it and it worked as expected.

Hope this helps someone too.